# Debian systemd firewall or firewalld?

Tags: debian, systemd, firewall, firewalld

I have run into some issues with the Firewall configuration for Debian 10 Buster:

```
[agp@debian10 ~]$ systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-07-31 07:12:13 CEST; 16min ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
 Main PID: 721 (firewalld)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 43.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/firewalld.service
           └─721 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid
[agp@debian10 ~]$ systemctl status nftables.service
● nftables.service - nftables
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nftables.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2021-07-31 07:12:06 CEST; 16min ago
     Docs: man:nft(8)
           http://wiki.nftables.org
  Process: 387 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nft -f /etc/nftables.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 387 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

However, when checking systemd it reports "degraded":

```
● debian10 
   State: degraded
    Jobs: 0 queued
  Failed: 1 units
```

and checking the problem:

```
[agp@debian10 ~]$ systemctl | grep fail
● firewall.service               loaded failed failed    Add Firewall Rules to iptables
```

I checked several different forums and Debian Wiki pages, only to become more confused by deprecated information regarding iptables set-ups and nftable configurations which has superceded iptables in Debian Buster.

But here is were my question start:

Why are there 2 firewall services on my system, and what are their functions?

```
[agp@debian10 ~]$ systemctl status firewall
● firewall.service - Add Firewall Rules to iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/firewall.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-07-31 07:12:10 CEST; 2h 35min ago
  Process: 720 ExecStart=/etc/firewall/enable.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 720 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
[agp@debian10 ~]$ systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-07-31 07:12:13 CEST; 2h 35min ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
 Main PID: 721 (firewalld)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 44.9M
   CGroup: /system.slice/firewalld.service
           └─721 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid
```

Is the firewall.service something to configure with iptables or will this conflict with the working firewalld.service set up?

I appreciate your considerations, suggestions and attention.
Cheers!

Comment: firewalld is just a frontend to either iptables or nftables, which allows you to use its firewall-cmd to build the firewall instead of `iptables` or `nft`. Since both iptables / nftables are "volatile" (i.e. their rules are in memory), you'll need a systemd service to restore what you/it dumped to a file to make what you built "persistent" unless a frontend handles that for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

The `firewalld.service` is created when installing the `firwalld` package.

The `firewall.service` with `ExecStart=/etc/firewall/enable.sh` and the Description: `Add Firewall Rules to iptables` is created manually. The same service is mentioned in [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianFirewall) (see example scripts)

Comment: I take it then that the two are not dependent on each other.
I have read the Wiki you mentioned, but I was also diverted to https://wiki.debian.org/nftables, where the confusion began. It is difficult to grasp at what is iptables and what is nftables in Buster. This was on top of trying to discern what was firewalld.service or firewall.service. 
Thanks for your quick attention.